# How does std::less work if there is no explicit < operator?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, key, operator-overloading

I wonder how `std::less` works in a map with keys that have no specific `operator <` associated with them.

More specifically, I'm working with two libraries, each of them having their own specific implementation of points in 3D space:

```
class Lib1Point
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    // ctors, dtor and lots of fancy methods, but no further data members
};

class Lib2Point
{
private:
    double coords[3];

public:
    // lots of other fancy methods, but also no further data members
};
```

There is for neither class an `operator <` defined.

```
class SomeData;
std::map<Lib1Point, SomeData> m_pointData1;
std::map<Lib2Point, SomeData> m_pointData2;
```

How would these two maps sort their keys ? Would points be sorted in the same order? Can I trust this order in some way or is it compiler specific ? In case I cannot trust it, what would be the easiest way to force a specific order without having access to the source code of the point classes ?

Comment: If I am not wrong, these containers will not sort their keys at all. There is no obvious way to sort 3D points unless you define one.

Comment: You may provide your own Comparer in `std::map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get a compiler error when you try to insert elements into your container.

```
int main()
{
    std::map<Lib1Point, SomeData> m_pointData1;
    std::map<Lib2Point, SomeData> m_pointData2;

    m_pointData1.insert({Lib1Point{}, 1});
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b047e182f67ddd6).

which gives the error

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Lib1Point' and
>   'const Lib1Point')
>
> ```
>       { return __x < __y; }
>                ~~~ ^ ~~~
> ```

You could either define an `operator<` for your types, or write a custom function object `my_less` and pass this as the 3rd template argument to `std::map`

```
#include <tuple>

struct Lib1Less {
    bool operator()(Lib1Point const& L, Lib1Point const& R) {
        return 
            std::forward_as_tuple(L.x, L.y, L.z) < 
            std::forward_as_tuple(R.x, R.y, R.z)
        ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Lib1Point, SomeData, Lib1Less> m_pointData1;
    m_pointData1.insert({Lib1Point{1,2,3}, 1});
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71ae1cab4fc6b5c6)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Maybe I could just use tuple<double, double, double> as key type for my maps. This would certainly improve mutual interactions.